# How does go layout arrays of structs in memory?

Tags: arrays, memory, struct, go, memory-layout

```
type Point struct {
     x, y int
}

var arr [4]Point
```

How will the array be laid out in memory?

Will the actual objects be laid out side by side

```
[Point[x][y]][Point[x][y]][Point[x][y]][Point[x][y]]
```

Or will the array be a array of pointers, with the objects stored elsewhere, like Java?

```
[&Point0][&Point1][&Point2][&Point3]
```

Somewhere in the heap:

```
...[Point0[x][y]] ... [Point1[x][y]] ....  [Point3[x][y]] ... [Point2[x][y]]
```

Also, how will `make()` lay out slices in memory?

```
make([]Point, 10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 4 `Point`s will be contiguous in memory, as in your first example. If you want them to be pointers, then you'd need `[4]*Point`.

A slice of `Point` creates a slice that uses (points to) a backing array, where, again, `Point`s would be side-by-side (and `[]*Point` would be a slice of pointers to `Point`).

See http://research.swtch.com/godata for a good explanation of memory layouts of Go data structures.

Comment: Thanks! Wanted to make sure Go does not ref everything like java. Regarding your link, I have seen it before but it does not talk about array of structs.